# populate listview with json parser

Tags: android, json, android-listview, getjson

i want to populate listview with json parser. but i have following error:

```
12-12 22:49:39.812: ERROR/JSON Parser(1254): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

JSONParse:

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }

}
```

UpdateFromSite:

```
public class UpdateFromSite extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    TextView name;
    TextView description;
    TextView price;
    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newItemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //URL to get JSON Array   
    private static String url = "http://www.karocellen.com/newItem.json";
    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_ITEM = "NewItem";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    JSONArray NewItem = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.updateapp);
        newItemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //check internet connection
                Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
                ConnectionDetector cd;
                cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    new JSONParse().execute();  }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You don't have internet connection.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     }
                     }
        });
    }



    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameNewItem);
            description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.descriptionNewItem);
            price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.priceNewItem);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UpdateFromSite.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }   catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"network problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                NewItem = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
                for(int i = 0; i < NewItem.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = NewItem.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                   int price = c.getInt(TAG_PRICE);                  
                    // Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, Integer.toString(price));
                    newItemlist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listupdate);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(UpdateFromSite.this, newItemlist,
                            R.layout.updateapprow,
                            new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_PRICE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.nameNewItem,R.id.descriptionNewItem, R.id.priceNewItem});
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    });
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"network problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    }
```

myJSON:

```
{"NewItem":[{"name":"Roast Ground Coffee","description":"Folgers Medium Classic Roast Ground Coffee 339 oz","price":8},{"name":"Seattle coffee","description":"Seattles Best Coffee Level 3 Whole Bean 12oz","price":10},{"name":"Medium Roast Bean Coffee","description":"Dunkin Donuts Original Blend Medium Roast Whole Bean Coffee 12 oz","price":6},{"name":"Espresso coffee","description":"Starbucks Dark Espresso Roast Whole Bean Coffee 12 oz","price":12},
{"name":"China Green Tea","description":"Tazo China Green Tips Tea 20 filterbags","price":8},{"name":"China Organic Green","description":"Uncle Lees Legends of China Organic Green Tea 100 Tea Bags","price":15},{"name":"Black Tea","description":"Tazo Earl Grey Black Tea 20 count","price":10},{"name":"Chai Spiced Black Tea","description":"Tazo Decaf Chai Spiced Black Tea Latte Concentrate 32 oz","price":5},
{"name":"Passion Tea","description":"Tazo Iced Passion Tea 6ct","price":11},{"name":"Peach Iced Tea","description":"Lipton Diet Peach Iced Tea Mix 2.9 oz","price":12}]}
```

Comment: looks like your response is a string not json

Comment: print this string `json = sb.toString();` and show output.

Comment: print price in string format like "price":"11"

Comment: you are parsing does not look right. check my post with snap shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Looks like what you get is a String and you are trying to convert it into a JSONObject

You do a  `HttpPost` instead of HttGet

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
```

Should be

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
```

Your json

```
{ // json object node 
    "NewItem": [ // json array NewItem
        {  // json object node 
            "name": "Roast Ground Coffee", // string
            "description": "Folgers Medium Classic Roast Ground Coffee 339 oz",
            "price": 8 
        },
```

Second Mistake

```
catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"network problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
```

Displaying toast in `doInbackground`. you cannot update ui in`doInbackground`

Complete Example with Snap Shot:

test.java

```
public class test extends Activity {
       ListView list;
       Button Btngetdata;
       ProgressDialog pDialog;
       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newItemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

       private static final String TAG_ITEM = "NewItem";
       private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
       private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
       private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.test);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(test.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            newItemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   new JSONParse().execute();  

                } 
            });
        }


        private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
               pDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
                try {
                     Log.i("...............","Hello..............");
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://www.karocellen.com/newItem.json");
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    String jsonstring = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    Log.i("...............",jsonstring);
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
                     JSONArray newitem = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
                    for(int i = 0; i < newitem.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = newitem.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                        String  price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                        Log.i("...............",name);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                        map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                        newItemlist.add(map);
                    }  

                }   catch (Exception ex){


                }
                return null;

            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                pDialog.dismiss();
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(test.this, newItemlist,
                        R.layout.second,
                        new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_PRICE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3});
                list.setAdapter(adapter);                        

             }
        }

}
```

test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap
[image]

Comment: @sami you also made a http post instead of http get. i think that was your problem. Next tie make sure you do a get request to get data and make a post request to post something to server.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is not generating the JSON correctly,

```
"<!DOCTYPE"
```

seems you are feeding in some HTML before outputting your JSON string.

Comment: i explain my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580267/parsing-json-file-from-server

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your json response should be for price like...
{
"NewItem": [
    {
        "name": "Roast Ground Coffee",
        "description": "Folgers Medium Classic Roast Ground Coffee 339 oz",
        "price": "8"
    }
]
}
get price value as string and then you can cast it into (Integer value) in your code.
```

Comment: no, i have this error yet: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject