# parsing json file from server

Tags: android, json, getjson, mime

I upload a `json` file to my server. This is the [json file](http://www.karocellen.com/newItem.json) but when I want to parse it, it gives the following error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

which setting should I do in server? I only set `MIME`.
[image]

You can review my codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574800/populate-listview-with-json-parser)

Comment: can you print your response.? and better to add your code here.

Comment: post your json response from logcat

Answer (score 0):

example response:

```
{"rows":[{"Fname":"rahim","Lname":"Durosimi","Predictions":"4","Cpredictions":"3","Points":"15"},{"Fname":"Otunba","Lname":"Alagbe","Predictions":"5","Cpredictions":"2","Points":"10"},{"Fname":"Olamide","Lname":"Jolaoso","Predictions":"4","Cpredictions":"2","Points":"10"},{"Fname":"g","Lname":"ade","Predictions":"1","Cpredictions":"1","Points":"5"},{"Fname":"Tiamiyu","Lname":"waliu","Predictions":"1","Cpredictions":"1","Points":"5"}]}
```

equivalent code to parse after you receive the response in string.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content);          
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("rows");
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String fname = json_data.getString("Fname");
String lname = json_data.getString("Lname");                
   }




<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "your url here"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
echo $output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

Comment: i have done that, did you see my codes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574800/populate-listview-with-json-parser

Comment: oh i get it! it happened to me once the response you are getting from the server isn't exactly json data. my case was when i tried to convert the xml feed of a third party site to JSON using feedburner. Sorry That i didn;t notice the  <!DOCTYPE tag in the beginning. i use php to create the webservice its painless just 

echo json_encode($var); does the trick for me

see edits to a possible solution using a php proxy.